# Why does this async IO using promises generate a zero length file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, promise, bluebird

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with this code?  I'm trying to write a small number of bytes to a file and all I get is a zero length file with no errors reported.

I'm trying to use async file IO and bluebird promises in node.js to write some data to a local file.  I've successfully written a synchronous version of this function and an async version using callbacks.  But, because the callback version was nested hell and had all sorts of error handling problems and was not very easy to maintain, I thought I'd try a version using promises instead since this should be its forte (better error handling, less nesting, easier to sequence async operations).

Unfortunately, the promise version only results in a zero length file.  Here's the code for the promise version:

```
// at initialization time
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));


    // code in a function
    var header = new Buffer('[temperatures] {"formatVersion": "1", "fields": ["t", "atticTemp", "outsideTemp"]}\r\n');
    filename += ".new";
    console.log("async write started");
    var fd;
    fs.openAsync(filename, "w", 438).then(function(ffd) {
        fd = ffd;
        return fs.writeAsync(fd, header, 0, header.length, null);            
    }).then(function(args /* [written, buffer] */) {
        var written = args[0];
        console.log("bytes written =" + written);
        if (written !== header.length) {
            console.log("not all data written");
            throw new Error("not all data written");
        }

        // lots more data to write here

        return fs.closeAsync(fd);
    }).then(function() {
        fd = null;
        console.log(" async write finished");
    }).catch(function(e) {
        // if (fd) fs.closeAsync(fd);
        console.log(e, "data.writeData() - error writing data (new format)");
    });
```

I've done everything I know how to do for debugging.  All expected `console.log()` error messages appear in the desired order.  I've verified all return values and arguments along the way.  No errors are reported in any way.  I've removed the previous file before running it again.  I'm using the same arguments and filename in my callback version that works just fine (which seems to rule out a file permission issue).  I've rebooted the computer (which is a Raspberry Pi, by the way).

I'm stumped.  I assume this must be something silly I'm doing wrong in my use of promises, but I can't for the life of me see what's wrong.

Comment: +1 for using bluebird :)

Comment: This works for me. Can you make it more reproducible?

Comment: @simonzack - I'll have to see if I can reproduce it in a standalone node.js app.

Comment: @simonzack - Hmmm.  It works in a standalone node.js app on the same platform.  OK, apparently there's nothing structurally wrong with the code.  Now, I wonder what it is about the context of the app that could be causing it a problem?  This code doesn't appear to have any dependencies on anything else.  The only data passed in is the filename which does get created so that isn't garbage.  I've commented out all other code in this function and no change.  I don't see any accidental globals (also running in strict mode).  This is odd.  Any ideas what else to look for?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  This function works perfectly fine when it is called in the normal operation of the app.  And, if I look at the file that it generates while the app is still running, the file is fine.

But (and this is where the problem occurs), I'm also calling this function when the app exits.  And, guess what, you can't use these types of async operations in an exit event handler without causing problems.  It gets as far as creating the new empty file and then the app exits and that's where things are left (just the newly created empty file on disk).

This particular function has an argument passed in for whether the writing needs to be done sync or async (just for this reason) and I hadn't yet written the sync portion of the new promise style code (I had written the sync version of the other versions of the code I had used).

Odd mystery solved.  And, it was something silly.  Nothing directly to do with promises, but it was an async issue.

One other mystery is why the version of my code that was async, but used callbacks instead of promises did not show this issue?  Apparently, it finished it's job before the process exited, but the promise version didn't.

Comment: Interesting. What happens in the callback version, if you force the file write into another event thread with setTimout? And does the length of the timeout delay matter?

Comment: For the sport, would you be willing to run the Zalgo build of Bluebird and see if it exhibits the same behavior as callbacks here? Promises provide asynchronisity guarantees that callbacks don't but the Zalgo build removes them.

Comment: (Also, the appropriate thing to do here is probably to block and use synchronous versions of the functions since it's on an app-exit handler)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - how would I run the Zalgo build on my Raspeberry Pi?  Yes, I ultimately have to write both async and sync versions of this saving function so I can use the sync version upon app exit and the async version during normal app operation.  Kind of a pain, but I don't know of any other way around my issue unless I used the sync version all the time which I don't really want to do.

Comment: That sounds... depressing. I'll see if I can think of a clever way to only write the code once. Do you have control about shutting down your app?

Comment: Here is the Zalgo build by the way https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-is-the-sync-build

Comment: According to [`process.exit` docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) setTimeout callbacks wont be called, which probably means nextTick callbacks (the default bluebird scheduler) wont be called either. So using the Zalgo build just for this case should work but don't use it in general.

Comment: @Esailija - That sounds like the issue.  In this particular case, I think it's advisable for me to just write/use synchronous code for the save on process exit (which I already have done) and use the regular bluebird for my async code.  The only downside is that I had to write a little duplicate code (one version sync and one version async), but honestly the synchronous version is so darn easy to write (compared to the async version) that it didn't take me long.  Async IO, even with help from a good promise library is just a lot more work to write, test and cover all possible error conditions.